# dot chart showing triangle in d3 Java script

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Could someone help me with the code below, I want to produce a dot chart with triangles,
I am using the code below but all the triangles are on (0,0)

```
svg.selectAll("dot")
  .data(data1)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", sym)
  .attr("fill", "green")
  .attr("transform", "translate(50, 50)");
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vaahi.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a static translate like `translate(50, 50)` for all the points, I'd guess that they'll be drawn to the same point as well. Use something like this depending on how your data looks:

```
svg.selectAll()
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolTriangle))
  .attr("transform", d => "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")");
```

Answer (score -1):

You're currently not setting the position of each `path` in your code. You'll need to translate each triangle based on where you want it to appear.

I've attached an example below which places circles using `scalePoint` and `scaleLinear` but you can use whichever you need to fit your data.

```js
const data = [{
  x: 1,
  y: 1
}, {
  x: 2,
  y: 2
}, {
  x: 3,
  y: 3
}];

const height = 100;
const width = 100;

const TRI = "M 0,0 8,10 16,0 z";

const svg = d3.select("#svg").append("g");

const x = d3.scalePoint().domain([1, 2, 3]).range([0, width]);

const y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([1, 3]).range([height, 0]);

svg.append('g').call(d3.axisLeft(y));

svg
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

svg
  .selectAll()
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", TRI)
  .attr("fill", "green")
  .attr("transform", (d) => `translate(${x(d.x)}, ${y(d.y)})`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <svg id="svg" />
</body>
```